# Suggestions for displaying and storing lots of text in React Native

Tags: react-native, text, local-storage, react-native-flatlist

My app is a novel reader, would like to ask if I am doing right.
Say like I download a book from server.
The server will send a book which is separated to many chapters which each chapter is in the format of json to the user.
So to let the app store the book in local, I will use Async Storage to store each json file one by one. Which each book should be at least 1 million words.
And to display the text, I will load all json file(every chapters in that particular book) to a flatlist and user can scroll to read the book.

I am new to React Native and I am not sure is this a good way to do it which I am a bit worry of the performance.